# Vue 3 - Add props / attrs to slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I have a question about slots. I want to add props / attrs to a default slot like this:

```html
    // Component.vue
    <template>
        <div>Component conten</div>
        <slot :required="required" />
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts" setup>
        defineProps({
            required: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Without having to do this:

```html
    // Parent.vue
    <template>
        <Component required v-slot="{ required }">
             <input :required="required" />
        </Component>
    </template>
```

So the question is, is there a way to do this without passing props back and forth between component and slot?

I hope i made myself clear. If not, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [scoped slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to share data between parent and child without using props or slots?

Comment: Are you trying to have a default behavior when a component isn't set in a slot? Because I simply do not see the reason for using scoped slots in this way.

Comment: @NikolaGava I have changed the example code in my question. What i am trying to achieve is when a prop 'required' is set on <Component> i want to be able to pass that prop down to the slot inside Component.vue without having to go back in Parent.vue and pass it trough from a v-slot like in the code above. I could of course set the required attribute on both the slot and the component but that is not intuitive and error prone in my opinion. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The slot is essentially a template. It has no knowledge of components placed in it. Imagine if you put 3 inputs there, would you expect it bind "required" prop to every one? If you need required prop for something else inside Child component, then this is the only way to bind it to input element. If you don't, then just keep it in Parent component. As far as I know, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: @NikolaGava That's what i wanted to know. It is just not possible. Thanks for your time!